How to add additional delegate method to UITableViewCell
I am working with a new button in a UITableViewCell subclass.  I want this button to bubble up to the containing table in the same way a cell press action would act.  Is there a special way to do this?

If you want to get notification about button action. There are multiple ways to do that but Delegate and Callbacks are more popular than others.
Delegates: Delegate Method to UItableViewCell Swift
Delegates vs Callbacks: D: Delegates or callbacks?
